# react native : How do I put "onPress" inside the icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, searchbar

How do I put  this part

```
onPress={() => {setFilterModalVisible(!FilterModalVisible);}}
```

inside the Icon ?

this is my example code :

```
<Searchbar
                  icon={() => <Icon name="arrow-right" size={30} />}
                  placeholder="חיפוש..."
                  value={searchFilter}
                  onChangeText={(searchFilter) => setSearchFilter(searchFilter)}
                  returnKeyType="search"
                  onSubmitEditing={() => {
                    if (searchFilter != '') {
                      filterDrishot();
                    }
                  }}
                />
```

Comment: you are showing an icon in ```SearchBar``` component?

Comment: i edit my question ..

Comment: check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

[Expo Snack for above screenshot example](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/carefree-cookie)

Call the `onPress` function on `onIconPress`

[onIconPress docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/searchbar.html#onIconPress)

Your possible solution.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = React.useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
  const [FilterModalVisible, setFilterModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <Searchbar
        style={{ marginTop: 60 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={(query) => {
          setFirstQuery(query);
        }}
        value={firstQuery}
        icon="arrow-right"
        onIconPress={() => {
          setFilterModalVisible(!FilterModalVisible);
        }}
      />
      <Text> FilterModalVisible  {FilterModalVisible? " : True":" : False"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

PS: Run the app on android or ios emulator, web view is not rendering the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
<Searchbar
    icon={() => <Icon name="arrow-right" size={30} />}
    onIconPress={() => {setFilterModalVisible(!FilterModalVisible);}}
    ...
/>
```